# Printers not redirecting when RD session host role is installed (winserver 2019)

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2019

as the title says, printers will not redirect to the remote server when that role is installed, everything works fine if i remove the role, but the thing is, without the role i can't control the licenses (even tho the licenses adm role is still active), so i can't have more than 2 users connected at the same time

on one occasion, we disabled the host role, the printers showed up, we printed some files just fine, then activated the host role again and the printers continued to show up with the licenses working, but for some reason we are not being able to replicate that on new servers

we have tried pretty much everything, gpo seems to be fine, registry keys are ok, services related to this are up and running, the driver responsible for printer redirection is showing up in devices manager, drivers are installed both on the server and the client machine (like i said, everything works without the host role) but it simply won't work

i think i've read every other thread here and everywhere else from people with this same problem and tried everything, but no luck

appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share the policy settings you deployed on the session host? Are you using a Connection Broker? if so, can you share the settings you set in the collection? Do you want to allow printing with the Session Host role, or do you prefer fixing the multiple session issue and being able to remove the Session Host role?

Comment: @Swisstone it's basically the default gpo, we only made sure to disable the option to disallow printer redirection, other than that, it's a brand new installation without nothing yet changed. We are upgrading from a super old 2008r2 server, so it's not yet deployed. No connection broker. TBH, any of these solutions would work for us, our main concern is making the printers work (redirect) while being able to login more than 2 users simultaneously.